# [Flutter]I do not use Google Mobile Ads. However, the Google Play Console shows "com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" is declared

Tags: flutter, android-manifest, android-permissions, google-play-console

I do not use Google Mobile Ads. However, the Google Play Console shows "com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" is declared.

My app does not contain ads. Therefore, this declaration is not necessary.

What should I do?

I did wrriten about pubspec.yaml and AndroidManifest.xml

pubspec.yaml

```
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  responsive_framework: ^0.2.0
  otp_text_field: ^1.1.3
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.4.0
  rflutter_alert: ^2.0.4
  intl: ^0.17.0
  flutter_riverpod: ^2.3.4
  firebase_core: ^2.9.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.4.0
  cloud_firestore: ^4.5.0
  mailer: ^6.0.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.1.0
  fluttertoast: ^8.2.1
  intl_phone_field: ^3.1.0
  pin_code_fields: ^7.4.0
  uuid: ^3.0.7
  shimmer: ^2.0.0
  country_list_pick: ^1.0.1+6
  image_picker: ^0.8.7+4
  firebase_storage: ^11.1.1
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.3
  infinite_scroll_pagination: ^3.2.0
  equatable: ^2.0.5
  timelines: ^0.1.0
  firebase_messaging: ^14.6.0
  url_launcher: ^6.1.11
  vibration: ^1.7.7
  volume_controller: ^2.0.6
  hive: ^2.2.3
  hive_flutter: ^1.1.0
  purchases_flutter: ^4.12.0


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
  build_runner: 
  hive_generator: ^2.0.0
```

android > app > src > main > AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.xxxxx">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
   <application
        android:label="xxxx"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: can you share your manifest?

Comment: sorry , I forgot it . I did add manifest file